# Coordinate-free representation of invariant interval

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

Suppose event B is at the origin of space-time diagram. Let A and C be arbitrary events (A is in the backward light cone and C is on the forward light cone with B at the origin). The world line connecting A and C intersects the light cone at X and Y. How can I show that $s^{2}_{AB}=\tau_{AX}\tau_{AY}$ ? ($\tau$ represents proper time, $s_{AB}$ is the invariant interval between A and B)

[image]

Comment: If this is a school exercise, please add the homework-and-exercises tag.

Comment: This is a good question, and should be re-asked to meet guidelines. It's easy to show using coordinates. Redoing it in a coordinate free manner is a useful demonstration of coordinate-free techniques.

Comment: @JEB: _"This is a good question [...]"_ -- It's certainly a question on a topic in which I'm interested. _"should be re-asked to meet guidelines. [...] demonstration of coordinate-free techniques."_ -- I've asked a related, more general question (as [a math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029996/generalizing-stewarts-theorem-to-timelike-triangles-in-lorentzian-spaces-of-con), for fear of triggering "_guideline_ mobbing") and provided an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4066114/277973) which concludes by dealing with the above (Robb, 1936) as a "special case".